# Why does MSTest DeploymentItem fail when running all tests in solution?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mstest

I have a Visual Studio 2010 solution with several MSTest projects. One of the test projects needs a file in a specific directory to run.

```
[TestClass]
[DeploymentItem("ReportEngine.config")]
[DeploymentItem("Report Files", "Report Files")]
public class MyReportTests { }
```

These tests pass when I run only the tests in this project (or test class). The report files are copied to the test execution directory. These tests fail when I run all the tests in the solution. The report files are not copied to the test execution directory.

Why is there a difference and how do I make the two runs deploy the same items?

Comment: If you right click on those items in your solution are they set to copy? I'm wondering if you need to set them to copy always... just a guess.

Comment: yes the items are set to "copy Always". otherwise the [DeploymentItem] in projectscope wouldn-t work, too

Comment: "Report files" is relative to the Solution root, correct? Is that the case in your project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be a microsoft won-t fix issue.

Comment: Do you have a link to the KB or Connect issue that specifies this?

Comment: I asked the question in may 2011 and after 16 months and a bounty i was frustrated that there was no solution. So i made my own answer accepted.

Answer (score 4):

I originally gave you instructions to ensure that Deployment was enabled in your test settings. You said that it was.

> Make sure that you have deployment enabled for the test run.
>
> 1. Edit your `.testsettings` in the Solution Items folder
> 2. Select the Deployment category
> 3. Check the "Enable deployment" option
> 4. Click "Apply" and "Close"

However, since last time I answered, I learned that the [`DeploymentItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.deploymentitemattribute(v=vs.80).aspx) attribute only targets methods (and then, it seems only works on `TestMethod`s). It could never have worked the way you have it decorating a `class`. I also noticed your comment on your question (edited for grammar)

> Yes, the items are set to `Copy Always`, otherwise the `DeploymentItem` in the project test run wouldn't work.

There's a lot of [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/883270/problems-with-deploymentitem-attribute) whether this is necessary or not to make `DeploymentItem` work. I suspect that something we haven't identified yet is making tests pass when running them from the project. Please remove the `DeploymentItem`s *completely* and try your two test runs (from project and from solution) and see what results you get.

---

#### In Case Deployment Items are Working Despite the Documentation

Make sure that `ReportEngine.config` and `ReportFiles\` are where you and MSTest expect them to be. Relative file paths are resolved starting at the "RelativeRootPath". By default, that's the `$(SolutionDir)`. Unless you override it in the `testsettings`. Please check on that.

But, by default

```
[DeploymentItem("ReportEngine.config")]
```

is expanded to something like

```
[DeploymentItem("$(SolutionDir)\ReportEngine.config")]
```

then, for example, to

```
[DeploymentItem("D:\code\my-project\ReportEngine.config")]
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is **not** the solution to my problem. I alrady had these settings. Otherwise the test would not succeed on projectscope. I have several test-projects when i execute them all together (on solution scope) some fail because [DeploymentItem] is ignored. when i execute one test-project the tests succeed, Deployment works because the settings in the answer were made

Comment: Oh, sorry about that... the bounty stuff is a little awkward in this situation :(

Comment: +1, I needed to create a TestSettings file and add it to my unit test folder in my solution - then select that TestSettings file in Visual Studio.  It wasn't apparent from other documentation that I saw that I would need to create one to enable `DeploymentItem`s.

Answer (score 1):

Deployment items are notoriously flakey... Have you considered using MSBuild and editing your test project's `.csproj` file directly?

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
  <CallTarget Targets="DeployReportFiles" />
</Target>

<Target Name="DeployReportFiles">
  <CreateItem Include="$(SolutionDir)\Report Files\**\*">
    <Output TaskParameter="Include" ItemName="OutputFiles" />
  </CreateItem>
  <Copy SourceFiles="@(OutputFiles)"
        DestinationFiles="@(OutputFiles->'$(???)\Report Files\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')" />
</Target>
```

I don't know if MSBuild contains a variable for the current test directory... since it doesn't appear to be involved in the process.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a test case moves/deletes the file? According to [the MSDN article "How to: Deploy Files for Tests"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182475.aspx) the files are deployed only once:

> When you select a set of tests to run, all the items specified in their DeploymentItem attributes are copied before the test run starts.