# DeploymentItem in vs2012 Doesn’t copy files

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, deploymentitem

I want to add a deployment item to my test.

My solution structure looks like:

```
MySolution\
-- TestData\
  --addresses.xml
-- ProjectName.TestProject\
  --Internal\
    --MyTestClass.cs
```

I’ve tried to add the file with the following attribute:

```
[DeploymentItem(@"TestData\addresses.xml", " TestData")]
```

…what does not work
But if I specify the absuluten  file path, vs will copy the file.

```
[DeploymentItem(@"C:\Dir1\Dir2\TestData\addresses.xml", " TestData")]
```

Comment: There's quite a definitive checklist of gotchas for VS 2010 [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/883270/problems-with-deploymentitem-attribute). See if that helps?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Current folder for `DeploymentItemAttribute` defaults to output bin folder.
So you have to specify first parameter relative to that bin folder:

```
[DeploymentItem(@"..\..\..\TestData\addresses.xml", " TestData")]
```