# How to see the files of WorkingDirectory of QTAGent

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, microsoft-test-manager

I am running the automated tests from MTM on a test agent controlled by a Test controller.
In my project folder BankAutomation I have a folder called the SQLScripts and inside that the file called "EmployyeSearchQuery.sql" .But when my project tries to read the data from this .sql file It gets the following error.

Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\%user name%\AppData\Local\VSEQT\SQLScripts\EmployeeSearchQuery.sql'.

code I have :

```
FileInfo file = new FileInfo(@"..\..\..\BankAutomation\\SQLScripts\EmployeeSearchQuery.sql");

string strRecQuery = file.OpenText().ReadToEnd();

strRecQuery = strRecQuery.Replace("\t", "  ").Replace("\n", "  ").Replace("\r", "  ").Trim();
```

What I want is,
I want to see the files at path:'C:\Users\%user name%\AppData\Local\VSEQT' .Where can I enable this ?

And is the path 'C:\Users\%user name%\AppData\Local\VSEQT.." changes everytime or its fixed ? Is there a way we can change this ?

I looked at QTAgent.exe.config but there is no such path..
Is my relative path correct one ?

Comment: How do you deploy the file EmployeeSearchQuery.sql before running your tests?

Comment: its added manually and it has copy always set to true.

Comment: I suppose what you want is to get your tests run, that means to get EmployeeSearchQuery.sql file deployed correctly. If so, see my answer below.
I did not really understand your question about the path _C:\Users\%user name%\AppData\Local\VSEQT_. What do you mean with "Where can I *enable* this?"

Comment: If you use relative path like _"..\..\..\BankAutomation\\SQLScripts\EmployeeSearchQuery.sql"_ in your code it is relative to a _Deployment_ subfolder of a folder which is created in _C:\Users\%user name%\AppData\Local\VSEQT\QTAgent_ directory *each time* you are running you test. So when you have managed to deploy _EmployeeSearchQuery.sql_ to this _Deplyoment_ folder (see my answer  below) you will have to amend the relative path you are using in your code.

Comment: And if your question is really about proper deployment please consider to change the title so the next person facing the same problem would be able to find it easily ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly you have added *EmployeeSearchQuery.sql* to your Visual Studio project and set its property "Copy To Output Directory" to "Copy Always", right?

If so, this means your file will be copied to the **build** output directory.

If you need this file when running your tests, you have to deploy it.
You can do it using *Test Settings* file or using *[DeploymentItem]* attribute (especially if you want to deploy this file for a particular single test).

This article will help you: [How to: Configure Test Deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182475%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
(It's actually describing running test from *Visual Studio* but the deployment procedure is the same if you are running tests using *MTM*).

If you decide to use *[DeploymentItem]* attribute please check this: [Problems with DeploymentItem attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/883270/problems-with-deploymentitem-attribute), it will save you a lot of time.