# WPF combobox binding not working.. It is not showing the exact value

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, combobox, binding

I will show you the exact code and output of the code...

This is my linq .dbml file

[image]

This i the combobox cbx_contact code :

```
 <ComboBox Height="22.669" Margin="107.769,43.75,424.266,0" Name="cbx_contact" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsTabStop="True" SelectedValuePath="ContactID" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" IsEditable="True" IsTextSearchEnabled="True">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ContactName}"/>
                    </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
```

This is the .cs file :

```
public Contacts()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();
        cbx_contact.ItemsSource = db.Contacts;
        cbx_contact.SelectedIndex = 0;     
    }
```

This is the output view of the combobox :

[image]

[image]

Here in the drop down list of combobox i get all the values but when i select any value the text does not change it gives Contact_Manager.Contact....

I dont know what i am missing here...
I have binded combobox like this before also it was working at that time but here it is creating probs...
thanks in advance for the help...

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1844156/wpf-iseditable-true-combobox-filled-with-objects-displays-the-tostring-as-the-s

Comment: @andrew shepherd : sorry for that i searched it on stackoverflow but was searching with wrong key words... thanks again

Comment: it's something we all do :-)  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122928/generate-a-unique-temporary-file-name-with-a-given-extension-using-net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying the concepts from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1844156/wpf-iseditable-true-combobox-filled-with-objects-displays-the-tostring-as-the-s/2289925#2289925):

```
<ComboBox Height="22.669" Margin="107.769,43.75,424.266,0" Name="cbx_contact" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsTabStop="True" SelectedValuePath="ContactID" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" IsEditable="True" IsTextSearchEnabled="True" 
        TextSearch.TextPath=ContactName
         >
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ContactName}"/>
                    </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
```