# Is it possible to create one dummy file with extension `(.wav)` format?

Tags: c#, file, silverlight-5.0, wav

I am doing Silverlight application. which i need to save data into server.

Is it Possible to Save recorded stream in one dummy file.

```
 Stream stream = saveFileDialog.OpenFile();

 WavManager.SavePcmToWav(_sink.BackingStream, stream, _sink.CurrentFormat);

 stream.Close();
```

Instead of selecting user by `SaveFileDialog` I want to use `Dummy` file at runtime.

if it possible any one will tell i will greatly appreciate.Advance thanks.

Comment: Perhaps [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/581570/1220971) might help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [IsolatedStorageFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefile%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) to create a temp/dummy file without asking the user to select a file.

The IsolatedStorage is a restricted area for your silverlight application to store files and data.

```
 IsolatedStorageFile store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication (); 
 IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = store.CreateFile("dummy.wav");

 WavManager.SavePcmToWav(_sink.BackingStream, stream, _sink.CurrentFormat);

 stream.Close();
```

Another solution would be to store the data of your .wav file in a in-memory stream. This can be done by using a [MemoryStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream%28v=VS.95%29.aspx).