# Error creating file in C:\, using vb.net code

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I am trying to create a text file in C: using code (shown in picture)  It says access is denied.
Please help.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: You don't have access to the root folder.

Comment: have you tried to investigate this issue yourself? there must be a lot of documentation regarding this kind of issue!

Answer (score 5):

The root of the C: drive is protected (On Windows Vista, 7, etc), so users cannot write to it unless the process is elevated.

Try right clicking on your compiled exe and then `Run As Admin` to test this theory.

The solution is to save your file somewhere else. This may help- [Lemme Tell Ya Where to Stick It](http://vb.mvps.org/articles/vsm20090119.pdf) and [Where Should I Store my Data and Configuration Files](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/patricka/archive/2010/03/18/where-should-i-store-my-data-and-configuration-files-if-i-target-multiple-os-versions.aspx)

Or you may want to create a temp file: [How can I create a temp file with a specific extension with .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/581570/how-can-i-create-a-temp-file-with-a-specific-extension-with-net) - you *should* have the relevant permissions to save this file but it cannot be guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

The user, who executes the program has no rights to create a file directly into the c:\ drive.

Comment: @FurqanSehgal: If you could do that, then there would be no point in having a security system at all.

Comment: You have to use another path or execute the program as Administrator.
But you should handle the Exception for example with try catch ...


http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/0yd65esw(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score -1):

vsFilePath should be something like c:\log.txt not c: